# Passing SharePoint objects as function arguments. Is this bad?

Tags: sharepoint, moss, sharepoint-2007

I am building a webpart that includes a function with an SPList as one argument. The list being passed will grow over time which makes me concerned about a scalability issue. Should I worry about potential performance issues using this method?

If you can offer any insight on other SharePoint objects (SPSite, etc) pertaining to my question or provide a link to further reading on this topic, I would be very appreciative!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why would this be a problem? Do you expect the data in the list will be copied when you call the function? It won't be. SPList is a reference to an SPList object, and you'd only be copying the reference.

Otherwise, I can't think why there would be a scalability problem. Please indicate why you think there might be one.

Comment: That was my question exactly. I wasn't sure exactly how C# was passing the objects. One more question to satisfy my curiosity however: would there be any difference between declaring/passing the SP object with ref versus simply passing it 'normally'?

Comment: You haven't said what language you're using, have you?

References are references. If, for some reason, you passed a reference to the reference, then you're still passing a reference.

Answer (score 2):

If you want an insight on performance with SharePoint objects you should read about SPSite and SPWeb disposing. Every SharePoint developer should know about those.

http://blogs.msdn.com/rogerla/archive/2008/02/12/sharepoint-2007-and-wss-3-0-dispose-patterns-by-example.aspx

Answer (score 1):

To add to John Saunders answer, objects such as SPList, when instantiated, doesn't actually create a list of all that data in memory. Rather, it creates a connection with where the list data is stored in the database, and any calls on that object trigger it's own SQL on the backend. In essence, the SPList object is a reference itself. Passing it as a parameter is okay!